# insert javascript function inside repeated regions in dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, php, dreamweaver

I am having trouble in javascript to run together with repeated regions in dreamweaver. i found this script, I think also here. this one

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
        setInterval(function() {$('#status').load('include_status_icon2.php?empid=<?php echo $_GET['empid']; ?>');}, 2000);
    });
</script>
```

what it does is it refreshes the page, include_status_icon2.php.

this code is working actually but in single row(db row) only. but when I aplly it to my repeating region, like I said it only works on the first row. heres my repeating reigion

```
    <?php do { ?>
<tr class="bortopbot tabledetails">
<td width="7%" height="28" style="padding-left:15px; padding:10px;">
<?php if (@$row_view_account['userphoto'] == "") {?>
<a href="user_account.php?empid=<?php echo $row_view_account['empid']; ?>"><img   src="images/user/default.png" width="49" height="65" border="0"></a>
<?php } else { ?>
<a href="user_account.php?empid=<?php echo $row_view_account['empid']; ?>"><img src="images/user/<?php echo $row_view_account['userphoto']; ?>" alt="" width="50" border="0" style="padding:5px; border:1px solid #d9edf7;"></a>                            
<?php } ?>
</td>
<td width="8%" height="28"><a href="user_account.php?empid=<?php echo $row_view_account['empid']; ?>"><?php echo $row_view_account['empid']; ?></a></td>
<td height="28" style="padding-left:15px; padding:10px;"><a href="user_account.php?empid=<?php echo $row_view_account['empid']; ?>"><?php echo $row_view_account['lastname']; ?>, <?php echo $row_view_account['firstname']; ?></a> </td>
<td height="28" style="padding-left:15px; padding:10px;"><a href="user_account.php?empid=<?php echo $row_view_account['empid']; ?>"><?php echo $row_view_account['depname']; ?></a></td>
<td height="28" style="padding-left:15px; padding:10px;"><a href="user_account.php?empid=<?php echo $row_view_account['empid']; ?>"><?php echo $row_view_account['telepnum']; ?></a></td>
<td height="28" style="padding-left:15px; padding:10px;">
<div id="imageload" style="display:none;">
<img src="images/1-0.gif" width="15" height="15"/>
</div>
<div id="status" style="float:left;">
Loading Status <img src="images/1-0.gif" width="15" height="15"/>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } while ($row_view_account = mysql_fetch_assoc($view_account)); ?>
```

any suggestion? thank you guys in advance!

Comment: your div with id `status` is also repeating. ids should be assigned so that, in an _entire document_, there is only 1 element with that given id.  change the id to a class, update your code to look for `$('.status')` inside of the interval.

Comment: Thank you @watcher for the fast reply. I get what you mean. But can you provide an example code? My apology if my request is too much. I just don't know how to interpret it in codes. I'm not really a coder. I rely mostly in dreamweaver. Thanks!

Comment: Any sample code guys please :( Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go, sorry I missed your comment yesterday.  Change this:

```
<div id="status" style="float:left;">
```

to this:

```
<div class="status" style="float:left;">
```

and change this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('#status').load('include_status_icon2.php?empid=<?php echo $_GET['empid']; ?>');
}, 2000);
```

to this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('.status').load('include_status_icon2.php?empid=<?php echo $_GET['empid']; ?>');
}, 2000);
```

See if that gets you where you need to be.

Comment: It worked @watcher! thanks a lot! but sadly I realize that my logic is actually incorrect :( .. The tables starting from <?php do }?> will juts show the list of the records from recordset right? and there's no URL parameter providing to ".load('include_status_icon2.php?empid=<?php echo $_GET['empid']; ?>');"} so what happen is the include_status_icon2.php is empty. is it possile for include_status_icon2.php to grab the value of the recordset set? let say I have 5 rows of different user account, include_status_icon2.php should display the record relatively to the record per row? tnx in advance!